# Undefined variable: users

Tags: php, laravel, view

> Undefined variable: users (View: C:\Users\Vitoria\Desktop\Laravel\resources\views\painel.blade.php)

Painel.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       <title>BEM VINDO ADMNISTRADOR</title>
   </head>

<body>


    <form method="POST" action="painel">

    @foreach ($users as $user)
        <h1> BEM VINDO ADMINISTRADOR!</h1>

        <p>Nome: {{$user->Name}}</p> <br>
        <p>E-mail: {{$user->User}}</p><br>
        <p>Tipo: {{$user->Tipo}}</p> <br>
        <p>Estado: {{$user->Ativo}}</p>     

    @endforeach

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ClientsController

```
public function painel()
{
    $user = \App\User::all();
    return View('/painel');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa passar a variavel `$user` atraves da função `view()`

```
$user = \App\User::all();
return view('painel', ['users' => $user]);
```

O segundo parâmetro de `view()` é um `array` com o índice sendo o nome da variável que sera usada na view, então se você quiser por exemplo usar outro nome de variavel na `view` faça:

```
return view('painel', ['meuNomeDaVariavel' => 'valorDaVariavel']);
```